# Storing full name of database user

Tags: sql, sql-server, qt

I have a QT application which uses database with several users (teachers in my case). I also have a table with teachers' names and information about them. Teacher logs in with his username and password at the beginning and then I need his full name somewhere in the program.

How should I retrieve it? Is there some way to store it in the table of db users? Or should I add column with username to my *Teachers* table? (It is my first application where I use databases so I'm sorry if this was asked before, I have no idea what I should google)

Database structure: https://yadi.sk/i/EmNwwsl7ia5JS

Comment: Are your tables already created ? I this case can you provide us the structure ?

Comment: Provide the table schema and we can discuss clearly

Comment: I added database structure into the description

Answer (score 1):

It's better to add two columns, for first name and last name, in the table where the username exists.  So by using the username we can fetch the full name from the table.

Comment: Username is stored not in my DB but in a system table of users of DB (as far as I understand how it works)